# How to call post API inside the nuxt.config generates()

Tags: nuxt.js

How to call post API inside the `generate`, which required a lot of dependencies from other APIs as well.

```js
generate: {
    // create an array of all routes for generating static pages
    // careful, this is only used by `npm run generate`. These must match SPA mode routes
    routes: function () {
      const data=[{treeid:"122"}]
      return axios.post(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',data
      )
      .then((response) => {
          let users = response.data.map((user) => {
              return {
                route: '/users/' + user.id,
                payload: user
              }
          });
          return ['/some-other-dynamic-route-or-array-of-routes/', ...users]
       });
     }
   }
```

Here I want to call the post API but it requires one more dependenies API for `treeid`,I defined here it as statically but if I want dynamically then what I have to do for it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.

You are trying to call 2 async functions in your routes function?
That shouldn't be a problem?
Or are you trying to pass extra variables to the function so that when it runs it will use those?
You could create your own "hook" of sorts for that

```js
// nuxt.config.js
generate: {
    routes: async () => {
      const treeIds = await getTreeIds(); // call your function that fetches the treeIds
      const users = await axios.post(
          'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', data
      );
      const routes = users.data.map((user) => {
        return {
          route: '/users/' + user.id,
          payload: user
        }
      });
      return ['/some-other-dynamic-route-or-array-of-routes/', ...routes]
    }
  }
```